# Should we get the mean of measurements or mean of calculations?

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements

Let's say we're given a set of 10 length and width measurements (with slight variance due to uncertainties), and we want to find the area.
Should we

1. Take the average of the length and multiply it with the average of the width

or

2. Calculate the area 10 times and take the average of the area?

I have a feeling that it might be option 1, since it gives the best estimate of the length and width. But I do not know how to disprove option 2.

Thanks in advance!

Example Measurements:
Length (cm): 10.02, 10.11, 10.08, 9.98, 9.99, 10.02, 10.11, 10.08, 9.98, 9.99

Width (cm): 4.97, 5.10, 5.06, 4.99, 4.99, 4.97, 5.10, 5.06, 4.99, 4.99

Comment: Why would their be a difference?

Comment: Because each measurement has a slight variance.

Comment: why calculate the are only 10 times? You have 10 measures of width for ech mesure of lenght, so you have 100 estimates for the area. If you take the mean value of these 100 values you get exactly the product of the mean values of width and lenght

Comment: Maybe the example was a bad example, but basically I'm trying to solve a question about finding a spring constant given varying values of mass and period. So I cannot multiply the values of seperate sets seperately.

Comment: Calculating expression involves it's own expression error, which needs to be evaluated. So usual way is to operate with _average_ values of measurements substituting them into required formulas. Otherwise, How you will evaluate your area formula error if somebody will ask you to do this ? See more here: [Calculating the uncertainty on an expression](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/390312/calculating-the-uncertainty-on-an-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 10 length measurements and 10 width measurements, and you cannot match up specific lengths with specific widths, you cannot justify preferring any particular 10 combinations out of the 100 possible combinations. So you average the 100 possible products, which is the same as multiplying the average length and the average width.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't really solve my issue as the example I gave was actually different from my actual use case, but that's an error on my part. Since your reply answers the question I posted, I will mark it as the answer. Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: It is important to know whether there is variation in the experiment or just variation in measurement of the same thing if you are trying to get benefit from using matching results together.

Comment: @AngryPants Aha, an XY Problem.